# Trivality of principal bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $\pi : P \rightarrow M$ be a principal G-bundle. There are topological properties of M and G that imply the triviality of the principal bundle?

Comment: You apparently pasted P \rightarrow{\pi} M in there so it didn't render in Mathjax. Please explain what it is.

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry, I have corrected the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $G$ or $M$ are contractible then the bundle is trivial.

Comment: In some way we can use the homotopies to construct a global section of the principal bundles which gives the triviality, am I right?

Comment: yes, we can use the motopy to construct the trivial section.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @TsemoAristide how do you show that if $G$ is contractible then the $G$-bundle is trivial? Is there a standard reference for this proof?